# Get public key from private ED25519 Go

Tags: go, cryptography, ed25519

I am attempting to extract a public key from a private key using ED25519 with Go.

I pass my private key byte value into my method, create a new ed25519 private key struct from it, and then use the `.Public()` method to retrieve the public key.

```
pk := ed25519.PrivateKey(privateKey).Public()
cpk, ok := pk.(ed25519.PublicKey)
if !ok {
    return nil, errors.New("problem casting public key to ed25519 public key")
}
```

It's not erroring but the resulting public key byte is always empty, is there something I'm doing incorrectly when creating the private key struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ed25519](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ed25519/) package has this important comment in the overview:

> ... unlike RFC 8032's formulation, this package's private key
>   representation includes a public key suffix to make multiple signing
>   operations with the same key more efficient. This package refers to
>   the RFC 8032 private key as the “seed”.

This means that it uses the following equivalences and terminology:

- **RFC 8032 private key**: 32 bytes, known as "**seed**" in this package
- **RFC 8032 private key and public key** concateneated: 64 bytes, known as "**private key**" in this package

If you already have a 64 byte slice consisting of RFC 8032 `<private key><public key>`, you can use the code in your question.

If you only have the a 32 byte slice consisting of RFC 8032 `<private key>`, you need to calculate the public key as follows:

```
// Compute the full 64 byte <private key><public key> from the private key
priv := ed25519.NewKeyFromSeed(32bytePrivateKey)

// Print out the public key (the last 32 bytes)
fmt.Println(priv.Public())
```

**Please note**: `ed25519.PrivateKey` and `ed25519.PublicKey` are both `type []byte`.

Comment: In my tests this seems to bring back a different public key to the one that is associated with the private key.

My tests pass if I do 

 publicKey := make([]byte, ed25519.PublicKeySize)
 copy(publicKey, pk)

With my private key, is this incorrecct?

Comment: Something is wrong. In the go package, the first 32 bytes of `ed25519.PrivateKey` are the private key (as defined by RFC 8032), the last 32 bytes are the public key (again, as defined by the RFC).